# Seeking a new tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-wiki

This question is motivated because of [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/general-puzzle-categories-and-are-there-any-emotional-puzzles).

I've created the tag **puzzle-logy** for it, out of need, but it was subsequently removed by the moderators. I don't argue with that decision, nor was I in particularly keen on the tag, but I think there is still an unsolved issue here:

I was looking for a tag, and couldn't find an appropriate one. This question is about *finding* or *creating* a suitable tag.

I wanted to tag the question as a question **about puzzles in general** (as opposed to a *particular* puzzle, or the process of *puzzle-creation*.). A tag about "*the science of puzzles*" (if there is one). That's why I created *puzzle-logy* in analogy to *bio-logy*, *geo-logy* etc.

I wanted questions tagged with this tag to be f.e. about

- science papers on puzzles
- puzzle-theory (on an abstract level)
- people/organisations which dedicated themselves to puzzle-understanding (not solving!)
- etc.

### Do you find such a tag useful?

### What would be a good name / wiki for such a tag?

In case that your answer to the first question is *no*, I instead need help with properly tagging [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/general-puzzle-categories-and-are-there-any-emotional-puzzles). I don't think it can be done with the currently existing tags. Maybe *puzzle-categories* would fit, but my feeling was, it's to specific and a tag which is only used once on site, is rather useless. **So please come up with suggestions.**

---

**Edit:**

> I have now created a tag called **puzzle-theory**.  Please edit it's wiki, if you feel it needs further clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a need for a tag, but even if there is, inventing a word and using it as a tag name is no good. Tags need to be discoverable. Someone looking for a question should have the idea of looking under that tag. An invented word cannot be useful as a tag.

Comment: @Gilles I agree with this. In the OP I stated that I would prefer re-tagging but couldn't quickly come up with something. Hence I'm also very okay with the deletion of the tag by the moderators. I just want to *complete* this issue, as the *no suitable tag* situation is unsatisfactory.

Comment: study-of-puzzles? puzzle-psychology?

Comment: How about "General-Puzzling" or "Generalized-Puzzle"

Comment: Theory of puzzles?

Comment: @xnor would puzzle-theory also work? Otherwise I like the suggestion...

Comment: @BmyGuest Yes, puzzle-theory sounds great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the comments to the question:
[xnor](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4551/xnor) suggested "Theory of Puzzles" which I revised into "puzzle-theory" and have created and used since.

> `puzzle-theory` = A question about categories, mechanics, or effects of puzzles in general, or about scientific research on puzzles.